# Strange UITableViewCell behavior in UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I've got a UIPopoverController created programmatically which pops up with the content from a UIViewController from a .xib. The UIViewController contains a (grouped) UITableView and a UITableViewCell "prototype".
When The popover pops up, the cell prototype is duplicated for all cells needed. The number of cells exceeds the size of the popover, so I can scroll through all cells.

When the popover pops up, everything looks nice, the cell labels are all left aligned. As soon as I touch the tableview to scroll, all cell labels suddenly align to center. When I scroll the cells outside and back in, the are left aligned again. After I scrolled all cells outside for once, they keep left aligned for the rest of their lifetime. I have no idea what is causing this... there is nothing in my code that alters the alignment of the cells. Here's some code:

```
UIViewController *editPopoverView = [[[ComponentViewEmptyEditPopover alloc] initWithNibName:@"ComponentViewEmptyEditPopover" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:editPopoverView];
aPopover.delegate = self;
[aPopover presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

From the popover viewcontroller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *theCell = nil;
    switch (indexPath.section)
    {
        case 0:
            theCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"typeCell"];
            if (theCell == nil)
            {
                NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.typeCell];
                theCell = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedData];
            }

            switch (indexPath.row)
            {
                case 0:
                    [theCell.textLabel setText:@"Empty"];
                    break;
                //
            }
            break;
    }
    return theCell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 1)
        return 420;
    return 44;
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I guess this is somehow related to cell reuse.

Update: Like I already guessed, it has to to with the reusing. When I do

```
theCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"theCell"];
```

everything works fine. However, I want to be able to change the design of the cell through interface builder...

Update 2: If I comment out the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier line, all cells will go back to center alignment after they scroll in.

Comment: Does it change things if you load the cell from the nib when the cell cache returns nil instead of the archive/unarchive logic?

Comment: @PhillipMills No, same thing happens.